# Enabling crontab logging on openSUSE

Tags: cron, crontab, cronjob

I am trying to enable the crontab log on openSUSE 11.3. I searched the web but couldn't find how to do it. I only find information about Ubuntu. Tried editing the /etc/rsyslog.d/remote.conf file but I don't have such on my system. So how to activate Cron logging and where to search for the logs? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I can't find it either, try this

```
> /your/log/destination.log 2>&1
```

it must be somthing like

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * /home/rainx/wp.sh > /your/log/destination.log 2>&1
```